# Having trouble updating a database PHP/mysql [noob]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm just having a bit of trouble with updating a database via a php form process, I've tried various things thus far to get it working but to no avail, All the pages seem to be working except for the _process.php itself;

```
  <?php
    /*saves the form data to the database */

    //read data passed via form
    $cabinID = $_POST['txtcabinID'];
    $cabintype = $_POST['txtCabinType'];
    $cabindesc = $_POST['txtCabinDesc'];
    $pricepern= $_POST['txtppN'];   
    $priceperw = $_POST['txtppW'];
    $photo = $_POST['txtPhoto'];

    //connect to server and database 
    include 'sqldb_connect.inc.php';

    //set up query
             $query =  "update tblCabins set
            cabinType='$cabintype' 
            cabinDescription='$cabindesc', 
            pricePerNight='$pricepern', 
            pricePerWeek='$priceperw', 
            PHOTO='$photo', 
            where cabinID ='$cabinID'"; // important

    //execute query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(!$result)
    {
        mysql_close();
        exit("Query failed");
    }

    mysql_close();
    exit ("Cabin updated successfully");    
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see any problems within the page that stand out?
Appreciate it :)

Comment: Some advise: When you are developing you dan do this: `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`, this will give you a descriptive error of the problem in your query. Aside from that, don't use `mysql_*` functions, the extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions instead

Answer (score 1):

Comma is missing in the query:

```
 $query =  "update tblCabins set
            cabinType='$cabintype' 
                                  ^
            cabinDescription='$cabindesc', 
            pricePerNight='$pricepern', 
            pricePerWeek='$priceperw', 
            PHOTO='$photo', 
            where cabinID ='$cabinID'";
```

Try with,

```
 $query =  "update tblCabins set
            cabinType='$cabintype',
            cabinDescription='$cabindesc', 
            pricePerNight='$pricepern', 
            pricePerWeek='$priceperw', 
            PHOTO='$photo', 
            where cabinID ='$cabinID'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one comma and one comma too many:

(Rewrite)

```
$query = "UPDATE tblCabins SET
    cabinType='$cabintype', 
    cabinDescription='$cabindesc', 
    pricePerNight='$pricepern', 
    pricePerWeek='$priceperw', 
    PHOTO='$photo' 
WHERE cabinID ='$cabinID'"; // important
```

- One missing after `cabinType='$cabintype'` and one too many for `PHOTO='$photo',`

---

**Error reporting:**

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**
- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php**

---

**Footnotes:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo).

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: I'm probably wrong here, but I thought MySQL was actually OK with an extra comma at the end?

Comment: It's just good practice @ChristopherWirt

Comment: Yeah, of course :) I just honestly wasn't sure anymore. 8 years of PHP and MySQL and you still question things like "can you put a comma there..?"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, PDO takes care of extra commas. @ChristopherWirt

Comment: THAT one I know for sure, which is why I can never remember.

Comment: I rather not take any chances myself with erroneous commas. @ChristopherWirt

Answer (score 1):

```
cabinType='$cabintype' 
        cabinDescription='$cabindesc',
```

You're missing a comma. Should be

```
 cabinType='$cabintype',
        cabinDescription='$cabindesc',
```

Also, just a note, as soon as you start feeling comfortable with mysql_query, I'd recommend skipping STRAIGHT into PDO and using prepared statements. It makes your SQL easier to read, and a lot safer :)